# Removing special character in data in databricks

Tags: pyspark, error-handling, special-characters, databricks, mapr

My company is in a migration project from MapR to databricks, and we have the following piece of code that used to work fine in this platform, but once in databricks it stopped working. I noticed that this is failing with this specific regular expression because this is not getting any error with others.

The Error is "Error while obtaining a new communication channel", and after that, we can not continue writing code and testing, something breaks.

I am attaching a screenshot for reference.
[[image: Error while obtaining a new communication channel1]

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as pyfunc

df=spark.read.parquet("/mnt/gpdipedlstgamrasp50565/stg_db/intermediate/ODX/ODW/STUDY_REPORT/Current/Data/")

df.count()

df = df.withColumn('CSR_RESULTS_SUMMARY', pyfunc.regexp_replace(pyfunc.col('CSR_RESULTS_SUMMARY'),u'([\ud800-\udfff\ufdd0-\ufdef\ufffe-\uffff+])',''))

df.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is caused by the `u''` in the regex pattern you pass to `regexp_replace` function. You should use `r''` for python raw string:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'column',
    pyfunc.regexp_replace(pyfunc.col('column'), r'[\ud800-\udfff\ufdd0-\ufdef\ufffe-\uffff]+', '')
)
```

Or use two backslashes `\\` to escape:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'column',
    pyfunc.regexp_replace(pyfunc.col('column'), '[\\ud800-\\udfff\\ufdd0-\\ufdef\\ufffe-\\uffff]+', '')
)
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I will test your solutions and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I tested your suggestion but it did not work for me. I wanted to show you a screenshot but I do not know how.

Comment: Hi @EimisPacheco, do you get the same error? maybe you can paste the error message using https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, this is not showing me any error but it is not removing the special character either. :(

Comment: @EimisPacheco do you have an example of input data so that I could reproduce it? Also, have you tried with `r'([\ud800-\udfff\ufdd0-\ufdef\ufffe-\uffff+])'`?